# JQM-like slide transition towards tab item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions, slide

I'm currently working with twitter bootstrap 3. I'm trying to make this FAQ dialog box[image: entekr image description here]

Lookin' well. But now I want the user to go to another tab in the dialog box by clicking on one of the list items, via a slide transition. Quite similar to jquery mobile.

My question is: What would be the best way to do this in bootstrap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to put Tab list inside the `model-body` itself. There will be no chance of any `conflict`

see the example below:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne"> Collapsible Group Item #1 </a> </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
        <div class="accordion-inner"> Anim pariatur cliche... </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```